# problems with pointers to copy characters

Tags: c

I have problems with getstring. I do not know why it does not work, the output in the main function printf do not put nothing

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *getstring(unsigned int len_max)
{
    char *linePtr = malloc(len_max + 1); // Reserve storage for "worst case."
    if (linePtr == NULL) { return NULL; }
    int c = 0;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while (i < len_max && (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF){
        *linePtr++ = (char)c;
        i++;
    }

    *linePtr = '\0';

    return linePtr;
}

int main()
{

    char *line = getstring(10);

    printf("%s", line);
    free(line);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably need to familiarise yourself with how to debug your small programs: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `linePtr` points to the *end* of the string containing the input line, not the beginning, because you do `linePtr++` during the loop.

Instead of incrementing `linePtr`, use `linePtr[i++]` to store each character during the loop.

```
char *getstring(unsigned int len_max)
{
    char *linePtr = malloc(len_max + 1); // Reserve storage for "worst case."
    if (linePtr == NULL) { return NULL; }
    int c = 0;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while (i < len_max && (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF){
        linePtr[i++] = (char)c;
    }

    linePtr[i] = '\0';

    return linePtr;
}
```

If you really need to do it by incrementing a pointer, you need to save the original value of `linePtr` in another variable, and return that rather than the one that you increment.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you are returning the end of your buffer, You need to keep a copy of linePtr or to index it. (You are incrementing it in your loop);